# Mapping logic for converting a pattern in excel or database

Tags: regex, excel, database, pattern-matching, data-conversion

I have thousands of mapping pattern that I need to convert. Attached is the image which shows the source value which I need to convert into Target values.

[image: Source Pattern vs Target Pattern]

Few of the rules that I am able to decipher are below: -

1. If the dash ('-') is just before any value then it needs to convert to pipe ('|')
2. If there are multiple dashes in the middle e.g. 4 dashes, then they would converted to 4 pipes and 3 dashes as shown in second example in order to show 3 empty fields (|-|-|-|)
3. If there are multiple dashes at the end e.g. 3 dashes, then they would be converted to 3 pipes and 3 dashes as shown in first example in order to show 3 empty fields without pipe at the end (|-|-|-)
4. There would never be a dash at the beginning
5. There are in total 8 values. Each |-| is considered a empty value. Each field is separated by pipe.

I am looking at ways to convert the source values into intended target values using any software possible.

Comment: What *precisely* is the problem though - you don't know *any* programming?  If No then this isn't really a place for tutorials, and if Yes then why not try something out and see how it goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This quick user defined function appears to meet your requirements without regular expressions.

```
Function mapSource(str As String)

    Dim tmp As Variant, i As Long

    'strip leading hyphens
    Do While Left(str, 1) = Chr(45) And Len(str) > 0: str = Right(str, Len(str) - 1): Loop

    'split str to a maximum of 8 array elements
    tmp = Split(str, Chr(45), 8)

    'preserve an array of 8 elements
    ReDim Preserve tmp(7)

    'replace empty array elements with hyphens
    For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
        If tmp(i) = vbNullString Then tmp(i) = Chr(45)
    Next i

    'rejoin array into str
    str = Join(tmp, Chr(124))

    'output mapped str
    mapSource = str

End Function
```

[image]